# Multithreading: How to avoid hanging caused by worker thread erroring out

Tags: python, multithreading, exit, terminate

I created a script that executes multiples threads, where each thread makes a request to an API to retrieve some data. Unfortunately, one of the threads might run into a disconnection error (perhaps due to overloading the site's API), and as a result, the entire python script hangs indefinitely...How can I force the script to exit gracefully when one of the worker threads has a disconnection error? I thought using `terminate` would close the thread.

My code:

```
runId = sys.argv[1]
trth = TrThDownload(runId)
data = trth.data
concurrences = min(len(data),10)
p = pool.ThreadPool(concurrences)
p.map(trth.runDownloader, data)
p.terminate()
p.close()
p.join()
```

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. A thread that terminates with an exception shouldn't hang the app. Perhaps some threads are stuck in I/O operations? Tweaking the timeouts might help.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You really should try async programming.  I prefer `gevent`. At the top of your script just do this:

```
import gevent
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
```

Also, don't terminate or close before your join.  Just use join.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll give it a go.

Comment: eventually you will want to use the built in stuff like spawn.  But try it and see if it helps